# HttpWebRequest and lost connection

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream to make POST requests to the remote server. Let's presume that the network connection is lost during this process and response was not received. Is there any way to detect whether the request was sent to the remote server or not? Thank you!

Comment: I'm probably being dim, but wouldn't you receive an exception explaining the stream terminated unexpectedly when you call _EndGetRequestStream_?  I don't know the answer to that, but according to the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7de1x8cb) it does throw a variety of exceptions.

Comment: It trows "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server." exception on EndGetResponse. But as far as I understand this does not indicate that the message was not sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to know what the server received and processed without some response from it. You need to handle this at the application layer, with another request whose response you do receive.

That is, you'll detect that the connection was lost and you didn't receive a response, so your applications sends another request, either repeating the same request (which the server must handle appropriately) or sending a query "did you receive and process that request with transaction ID XYZ?".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've thought about this approach. I was hoping to find the the way to detect that the message was sent (not received). This will give an option to decide whether there is need to contact server regarding this message.

Comment: I'm assuming you had a successful call to EndGetRequestStream(),  you wrote some data to it and closed the stream. At that point, your data is in "the cloud". I'm reasonably sure you won't find a way to know whether or not it has been transmitted across the wire or not.

Comment: It trows exception on EndGetResponse. EndGetRequestStream with Write does not produce any exception even if the connection was lost before...It looks like there is no way to do what I wanted. Thank you anyways.